# Запрос на родственные записи

Tags: mysql, laravel

Запросом подвесил сервер.
Задача такая:
Есть некие товары, которые имею связи по категории и по городу.
Необходимо для любого товара выбрать 4-е случайных родственных.
То есть, сначала 4-е в той же категории и в том же городе, если нету, тогда в той же категории, ну и иначе любые 4-е или если вообще меньше 4-х, то где те, что есть.

Написал такой запрос (см. ниже), но apache кричит, что недостаточно памяти.

```
$ads = Ad::where('publish', 1)
->where('category_id', $cat_id)
->where('id', '!=', $this->id)
->inRandomOrder();
    if($ads->count() > 4){
        $res = $ads->where('city_id', $city_id);
        $count = $res->count();
        if($count >= 4){
            $res = $res->take(4)->get();
        }else{
            $res = $res->union($ads->take(4-$count))->get();
        }
    }else{
        $res = $ads->get();
    }
    return $res;
```

Comment: Реши эту задачу сортировкой, а не отбором. Сортируешь по совпадению категории, потом по совпадению города. И берёшь первые 4 записи. Всё.

Comment: Способ не подходит. Во-первых результат должен быть рандомным. Вво-вторых...Ну ок отсортировал по категориям 1,1,1,1, 2,3 , а мне нужно из второй и смысл был сортировать?

Comment: Какая собсно разница, в какой момент отбирать потребное количество - до сортировки или после? Так хотя бы сервер не повесится... А если нужен рандом - так это третьим уровнем сортировки делается.

Comment: Дело не в порядке отбора, а в сути сортировки. Отсортируются либо снизу вверх либо сверху вниз. Т.е я выберу 4 первых с минимальным id, а нужно с определенным

Comment: *Т.е я выберу 4 первых с минимальным id* Я же сказал *сортировать по **совпадению** категории*, а не *сортировать по категории*...